# Appending members to Dictionary in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am in the process of adding members to the dictionary for the same key dynamic which will be processed to create json objects.

For example sample code

```
data_Dict = dict()
data_Dict['1'] = {'Key': '1111',}
data_Dict.setdefault('1',  []).append({ 'Val':'Name'})
```

I am getting error
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do something like:

```
data_Dict = dict()
data_Dict['1'] = {'Key': '1111'}
data_Dict['1']['Val'] = 'Name'
```

This will give you something like:

```
>>> print data_Dict
{'1': {'Val': 'Name', 'Key': '1111'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `.update` will do what you're looking for

```python
data_Dict = dict()
data_Dict['1'] = {'Key': '1111'}
data_Dict['1'].update({'Val':'Name'})
print(data_Dict)
# {'1': {'Val': 'Name', 'Key': '1111'}}
```

Comment: I don't know that you want update here. Could be quite expensive. just `data_dict.setdefault('1', {})['Val'] = 'Name'` might be better. I don't understand the incoming data for this question.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Why are people using `Dict.setdefault`? Isn't subscripting (`mydict['key'] = 'value'`) standard?

Comment: @u8y7541 Well as I already said I don't really understand where the data is coming from based on OP's example. `setdefault` covers the case where the key may or may not already be in the dict.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Subscripting also covers the same case. I have never heard of using setdefault for assigning values in dictionaries.

Comment: @u8y7541 No, starting with `my_dict = {'1': {'key': '1111'}}`, `my_dict['2']['1'] = 'value'` raises `KeyError: '2'`. `my_dict.setdefault('2', {})['1'] = 'value'` just works.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's not good for readability. Besides, OP had already defined `data_Dict['1']` so `data_Dict['1']['Val'] = 'Name'` would work.

Comment: @u8y7541 that may just be an example. This is supposed to be JSON and so may be quite complex. It might be overkill here, you're right. However, there is no "readability" argument to make between setdefault and regular assignment, because they are not equivalent. For comparison, normal assignment code would require a `try: my_dict['2']['1'] = 'value'; except KeyError: my_dict['2'] = {'1': 'value}`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That's why I use default dict from collections for JSON. It defaults all values to {} if I don't declare them.

Answer (score -1):

What I don't understand is where dict.setdefault comes in to this... the solution is very simple.

When you call `data_Dict['1']` you get the element assigned to `'1'` in the dictionary. This is the dictionary you want to add `'Val': 'Name'` to. Logically, you should be able to assign `'Val': 'Name'` to it by typing it as:

`data_Dict['1']['Val'] = 'Name'`

Here's how Python interprets that.

```
  What is assigned to '1' in the dictionary     Key named 'Value' in data_Dict['1']
                     |                                           |
                     |                                           |
                     |                                           |
              data_Dict['1']                                 ['Value']



        Assign to                      String (Name)
            |                               |
            |                               |
            |                               |
            =                             'Name'
```